# How to create a custom dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dialog

I'm working on a flutter application, I want to show a dialog above button if clicked as this image:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: I think you should try Overlays.  Check link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuXKwjv2gTY
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html

Comment: Your question is missing quite a few elements to fit a StackOverflow question profile. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask